# storing/displaying stats of a character

Tags: jquery, database, laravel

I'm using Laravel 5 and I have characters who have equipements that bring them caracteristics.
My entities look like :

```
character --> character_equipement <-- equipement  --> stats_equipement <-- stats
```

I don't know how to display the stats of the character because they depends on the equipment he is geared with.

I fistly wanted to manage it with jQuery : when I load the page (something like 'myUrl/character/78'), I do an ajax query to extract this way :

FOR this character I want all stats from all equipment he is geared with.

Then I display them into my divs.

- it sounds maybe stupid to do an ajax query at the loading of the page (I'm a beginner so probably a dumb question)
- I'll probably have trouble to display my div correctly because I'll have to check the value to know if this kind of stat goes into this div for every single stat I took

Secondly, I wanted to manage it through a model : 
I take a response where I sum all the identic stats through my query then I display them into my divs.

But this way, I'll probably have to go through my response every single div (I have at least 15 div) and I don't think that it's good for server performances.

Lastly, I intended to store all attributes in my character entity :

```
id_char, name_char, img_char, health_char, strength_char, wisdom_char, damage_char
```

etc...

Could someone help me to take the best approach? Or maybe give me another one!

**EDIT using eager loading :**

Here are what I tried. I firstly wanted to take only equipements from my character to debug it. This is what I did :

in my Character Model :

```
 public function equipements(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(EncyclopedieModel::class, 'stuff_equipement', 'id_equipement', 'id_equipement');
}
```

Then when I debugged it I have this response :

```
 select * from equipement inner join stuff_equipement on equipement.id_equipement = stuff_equipement.id_equipement
```

Which is fine... Then I debug the initial query which looks like this in my controller :

```
 public function getEquipementsChar(){
    return StuffModel::with('equipements')->where('id_stuff', 1)->get();
}
```

And then I debugged it and it returned :

```
"select * from `stuff` where `id_stuff` = ?"
```

I thought that this function will search the character 1 with equipements but I don't know why my function is not going through the 'with', it seems that my function is ignoring it.

Did I miss something?

EDIT 2 :

It had something with parameters I specified through my equipements() function. I modified them the good way and I'm now fine.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have models for all entities, you could do this using eager loading in laravel 5,

character.php (model)

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Equipement;

class Character extends Model
{

     public function equipements()
     {
         return $this->belongsToMany(Equipement::class);
     }
 }
```

Of course if you have one equipment each character, you can go with

```
$this->blongsToOne(Equipment::class);
```

This model will eager load equipements via pivot table i.e.

table_name: 'character_equipement'

fields: id, character_id, equipement_id

Now, equipment.php (model)

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Stat;

class Equipment extends Model
{

     public function stats()
     {
         return $this->belongsToMany(Stat::class);
     }
 }
```

same goes here, if you have one stat each equiment, you can go with

```
$this->blongsToOne(Stat::class);
```

This model will eager load stats via pivot table i.e.

table_name: 'equipement_stat'

fields: id, equipement_id, stat_id

Comment: You can simple call this by,

    $character = Character::with('equipments')->where('id',1)->first();

Comment: Thanks for help, I edited my initial post based on your answer... Something is still not fine but I think I'm going the good way.